# Python Decimal Calculation Is Not Precise

Tags: python, decimal, calculation

The result of `1 / 9 * 9` should equal `1`. However, Python returns `0.99999999999`...

```
    from decimal import Decimal
    import decimal

    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 256

    dec1 = Decimal('1')
    dec9 = Decimal('9')

    dec_result = dec1 / dec9 * dec9
    print(type(dec_result))
    print(dec_result)
```

I need a precise method for calculations,; hence, the usage of decimal vs. float.

Can anybody suggest a fix? Thanks...

Comment: Put the division at the end: `dec1 * dec9 / dec9`

Comment: This will not work as I am not in control of the order. The end user is.

Comment: 1/9 cannot be displayed as decimal. Use `fraction` instead of `decimal`.

Comment: When I did look at fraction, for several reasons, it was not suitable for the job. Checking again, "Changed in version 3.2: The Fraction constructor now accepts float and decimal.Decimal instances.". Will give it a shot.

Comment: calculate with 256 precision but round answers to 100 decimal precision

Comment: This is a nice hack, and it works. Thank you. Can anyone think of a more elegant solution?

Comment: This is not a hack, this is the standard way. For instance, that windows calculator, excel, whatever do that. You don't need that much precision, you only need 1 more digit that you display. Yes this is imprecise. Yes there are other ways to represent number that imply other compromises, for specific use cases. But as you did not mention a use case…

Comment: Fraction is the elegant solution here... 1/9 cannot be represented exactly with finite precision in base 10, which is why Decimal does not work. The other option is to use base 9, which may require a third-party package.

Comment: Fair enough... I think the solution / explanation provided by @rioV8 / spectras is the best way to go...

Comment: Thank you all... Learned bits and pieces which have been very helpful.

Comment: @spectras I suggest a few more digits precision than you need in the answer, you can add up  a lot of rounding errors if you do a lot of calculation before you display the answer, that is why the floating point unit uses 80 bits precision but doubles only store 64 bits

Comment: @rioV8 yes for sure. It is simpler to explain the idea with just one additional digit. Then in practice the optimal number depends a lot on what you do. And special care to what you compute with floats. For instance, catastrophic cancellation can happen no matter the number of extra digits one is not careful.

Answer (score 0):

**explanation of why this happens:**
This is not a precession error from python's decimal module.
Many calculating machines and many other programming languages behave the same way. Grab an old calculator, divide 1 by 9 and multiply it again by 9. You'll get the 0.9999999 that you got from python.
We, as humans can determine that the exact result is equal to one by simplifying the fraction `1 * 9 / 9 = 1`. But many digital calculating machines calculate the operation by going through each element one by one, basically dividing the operation into smaller operations. So for a computer, 1 / 9 * 9 is going to be like this: *Calculate 1 divided by 9. Multiply the result by 9*. If you do the calculation by hand, going through each sub-operation one by one, you'll get the same result.

**However:**  Even though from my perspective, 0.9999999 result is much accurate, many modern calculators and many modern programming languages such as *Python*, *JS*, *Java*, *C++* and even *C* handles this problem with their primitive data types. That mean's that if you are using primitive data types of those programming languages, `double` and `float`, you don't need to worry about this sort of precession problems. I tested both *JS* and *Python* and got similar results.

```
Python 3.8  
>>> a = 1.0  
>>> b = 9.0  
>>> a / b * b  
1.0
```

Comment: Both Mac OS and Windows calculators can do this. In other words, 1/9*9=1 is the result displayed. Try it out :)

Comment: @BurcakAkiska> no they do not. They merely round the result when displaying it.

Comment: That is because they probably use a newer data structure for calculating the operations. Probably one that takes the _limit_ of the data into consideration. Though the __Actual__ result must be 0.999999 (computer-wise).

Comment: I never claimed this to be an error. It is just a situation which broke parts of my solution. The whole reason I used Decimal instead of Float is the huge number of inconsistencies introduced to calculations. For example float_add = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 gives 0.30000000000000004 as the result. Will check numpy's Double though... Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the problem of accuracy is within the Decimal module itself

Normally doing this operation

> 1/9 * 9

Will give us the result as 1.0

**I Recomend You To Go With The Normal Division Itself**